# Python Selenium: How to dismiss a pop-up ad?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests

I am trying to automate a bunch of testcases that test all the input errors of a website and every test case works individually but when I run all testcases then I met with pop-ads every time and I don't understand how to dismiss them!

Any help is appreciated!
[Screen Shot of the ads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0BiC.png)

This is what my testcases look like:

```
def Name(self, TestData, ExpectedErrorMessage):
        #making the driver  
        driver = self.driver
        actions = self.actions  
        #find 'New Customer' element and click
        driver.find_element("xpath", "//a[normalize-space()='New Customer']").click()
        #find 'Name' element and click
        driver.find_element("xpath", "//input[@name='name']").click()
        #enter test data
        actions.send_keys(TestData).perform()
        #find the error message element and store in variable
        error_displayed = driver.find_element("xpath", "//label[@id='message']").text 
        #assert equal the error message
        self.assertEqual(ExpectedErrorMessage, error_displayed)

def test_NC1(self):
    """Verify Name field: Name cannot be empty"""
    self.Name(Keys.TAB, "Customer name must not be blank")
```

Comment: Find the element (usually a button) that closes the ad, and click it.  What is the difficulty?